# I want to add a specific section to products information block

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify-liquid, theme-customizer

```
I am using Ella Shopify theme, I want to add brand slider section to products information block before dynamic 'buy it now' button. Is there any way to do so. I am looking forward to your kind response
```

I am using Ella Shopify theme, I want to add brand slider section to products information block before dynamic 'buy it now' button. Is there any way to do so. I am looking forward to your kind response

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using swiperjs. [Here's the documentation link](https://swiperjs.com).